# Getting timestamp in the format of the Eloquent ones

Tags: datetime, laravel, laravel-4

I want to get a timestamp for the current time in the same format as eloquent pushes to the database.

Like: yyyy-mm-dd xx.xx.xx

How would i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-formatting) as DateTime class, so you can do:

```
$dt = Model::find(1)->created_at;

echo $dt->toDateTimeString();
```

To get it the way you need.